# In Android-ndk, How to make _fini( ) to be called when dlclose( ) is called?

Tags: android, c, android-ndk

We are using C libraries in our Android-NDK project. We are using dlopen( ) & dlclose( ) to work with our libraries in Android NDK. When we are calling the dlopen( ), the library's _init( ) is getting called as expected. But on the contrary, when we close the library with dlclose( ) call, the _fini( ) function is not getting called. We don't want to explicitly call the _fini( ) function after calling the dlclose( ) API. I'm testing these on API 24.

As per linux, the two functions _init( ) & _fini( ) should be called when we invoke dlopen( ) & dlclose( ) respectively.

```
void func( ){
...
   int ret = -1;
   handle = dlopen( "mylib.so", RTLD_NOW | RTLD_GLOBAL );
   ret = dlclose( handle );    // dlclose() is returning 0.
...
}

void _init( ){
   log("dlopen is loading the library");
}

void _fini( ){
   log("dlclose is unloading the library");
}
```

I have also tried changing the syntax of _fini( ) as below, but with no luck.

```
void _fini() __attribute__((destructor));
```

Even with the 'destructor' attribute as in the previous line, the _fini( ) is not getting called upon dlclose( ).

Since the _init( ) function is getting called upon dlopen( ), I'm sure that _fini( ) should also be called upon dlclose( ), so I should be missing something. We are using Android Studio to build the apk. Can anyone please help me out on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your dlclose() did not work, because it did not expect the library name as parameter. You should pass to it the handle that was returned by dlopen().

Comment: @AlexCohn : Thank you Alex, I had indeed passed the handle from dlopen( ) to dlclose( ) in my project code.I have made a mistake while asking the question. I have also edited my question correctly. The return from dlclose( ) was 0. Please let me know if I have to make any other changes to my code.

Comment: Are you sure dlclose() has worked? It's easy to check: if the handle can still be used for dlsym(), then _fini() is legitimately not called.

Comment: @AlexCohn : Surprisingly, the handle can still be used for dlsym() after the call to dlclose(). I was able to get the address of a function and could invoke the function too and all this after the call to dlclose() !!. This means that dlclose() has not worked as expected, But, dlclose() call returned 0. Is there any way, I can figure out why the call to dlclose() didn't work as expected.

Comment: @AlexCohn : Also, when I changed the signature of _init() as below to include the constructor attribute, the _init() function was getting invoked twice consecutively, So I removed the constructor attribute:

`__attribute__((constructor)) void _init() { //Some stuff. }` 

Can these issues be due to some wrong configuration in my CMakeLists.txt file. with only `void _init() {...}` the _init() is getting called only once.

Comment: After going through the link https://github.com/android-ndk/ndk/issues/887 . We are having some thread local data in our project code, but not in the small sample code that I'm testing. I'm also pretty sure that the library that I'm using to test _init() & _fini() has no other dependency.

Comment: You can try to call **dlcose()** again, and again, until it fails. That would mean that you exhausted the ref count of this library.

Comment: @AlexCohn : Sorry Alex, no luck with that approach, the dlclose() just keeps returning 0 & never fails. I tried
 '    while(iRet == 0) {
        iRet = dlclose(handle);
    } '
but this just goes on in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best advice I can give about `dlclose` is to never use `dlclose`.

`dlclose` is not specified to do anything other than inform the runtime that it *may* unload the library; the runtime does not have to do anything about it. For systems that do implement unloading (Android included) are not always able to do so because things like `atexit` handlers (or thread exit handlers, etc) cannot be run until the whole program exits, so any time a library registers such a handler it cannot be unloaded. That appears to be the case here.

The exact use case can cause the answer to vary, but for the cases we've seen where this sort of behavior cannot be removed (a plug in interface where plugins are expected to unload, then reload with all their state reset), the fix is to add explicit `Initialize()` and `ShutDown()` functions to the library. These need to be called by the library user rather than relying on `dlopen`/`dlclose`.

Comment: Thank you Dan Albert, Based on your suggestion, I have 2 questions. (1) The _init() is getting invoked as we expect, so can we retain the _init() call & make necessary changes for the _fini() or do we have to choose alternative to _init() also? (2) The breakpoint in _fini() was not hit when the application completely exited. So, _fini() won't be called at all ? Please let me know if I'm missing anything.

Comment: (1) If you ever need to reinitialize the library, don't rely on `_init()`. For any action that is guaranteed to happen only once, you can keep `_init()`.

Comment: (2) In Android, you are not guaranteed that your app will shut down gracefully. So, even if the library is normally unloaded, there will be situations when the system will kill the process immediately. You should not rely on `_fini()` or `atexit` handlers or whatever to have been executed.

Comment: @AlexCohn : Thanks for your replies Alex.